# Erroring displaying multiple images in one bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get all images from a mysql table and display them in a bootstrap carousel but all the images are showing at the same time i.e. static, they don't slide. What am I getting wrong?

This is the code:

```
 echo "<div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>            
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
                    <div class='item active'>
                    ";
                    foreach ($db->query($view_photo, array( 'offer_id' => $result['id_count'])) AS $result2){
                      echo "<img src='profile_pix/{$result2['photo']}' width = '150' height ='180px' style='padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;'/>
                     ";}echo " 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                      <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                      </a>
        </div>
";
```

Comment: see your console you must have some error

Comment: your upvotes seems fake :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are adding all images to the class item-active. If it is the class for the currently active item in the slide show, try add that class using jquery to the image.